How to map identity to a sigmoid?
Is there a way of smoothly defining a function that transforms the identity function to a sigmoid for a fixed range (say $[0,1]$)? What I want is to define a function $f(x,k)$ such that $f(0,k)=0,f(0.5,k)=0.5,f(1,k)=1, \forall k\in\mathbb{N}_0$, and, as $k\to\infty$,

where the limit should be a Heaviside step function.
Some thoughts: The function
$$
f(x,k) = \begin{cases}
0.5 \left( 1 + \frac{\tanh(k(x - 0.5))}{\tanh(0.5k)} \right)& \text{if }k> 0\\
x& \text{if }k=0
\end{cases}
$$
seems to do the trick, but I need to treat $k=0$ separately. Is there a better solution?

Typically the domain of a sigmoid function is the entire real line, rather than an interval. So the terminology doesn't quite match what you want.

Also, one way to interpret such a graph is as the CDF of some random variable on $[0,1]$. This leads to the example of the regularized beta function $I_x(x;k,k)=\text{B}(x;k,k)/\text{B}(k,k)$ as a possible candidate, with $k=1$ returning $I_x=x$. The only difficulty is that this is not an elementary function.

I don't know what you would consider as a better alternative, but maybe one example could be the following function for $k\geq 1$:
$$f_1(x,k) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad x \leq 0; \\
1,\quad x\geq 1; \\
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\tanh\left(\frac{k(2x-1)}{2(x^2-x)}\right)\right), \quad 0<x<1
\end{cases}$$
which is also piecewise, fit the examples point you want, fits in both extremes of its domain a perfect match with the constant functions that followed them, since in the edges all their derivatives equal zero, this at the cost that the function is no analytic at these points (is an example of a Non-analytic smooth function, actually I take it from the Smooth Bump Functions Wiki page), so $f_1(x)$ as it is defined, in principle, is actually smooth in the whole real domain $(-\infty,\ +\infty)$ (maybe, excepting when $k \equiv \infty$, scenario I am not qualified enough to review it in detail - sorry).
You could check the function here in Desmos.

Pretty interesting! I will have a read. Thanks

@samwolfe I am engineer, and I got shocked when I learned in those Wiki pages that no non-piecewise, so traditional, power series, cannot match a constant function on any non-zero measure interval, since it would violate the Identity theorem... its like math teachers lied to me my whole life! xD. But be careful since I am self learning this, it highly probable I got some misunderstandings, so be careful with this.
